# Xcode Exclude Specific Devices Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, ipod, info.plist

Our latest game uses a reasonable amount of memory and unfortunately crashes on the 4th generation iPod.

We'd like to exclude the iPod 4 using the Info.plist file.  Does anyone know if we can do this by device generation rather than using an app wide setting like Front Facing Camera etc.

The docs appear to suggest that this is feasible, unfortunately I can't find any examples, I'd like to do something similar to below, or otherwise we exclude iPad devices that ARE compatible with the game.

[ipod] 
  requires auto focus camera 
[iphone] 
  requires front facing camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot exclude based on the generation like that. You would have to exclude based on some other criteria, such as telephony (this would exclude iPod touches and iPads), or gps (this would exclude iPod touches and non-cellular iPads). There are other things as well that would give you different subsets of devices that you want as well. But there is nothing that you could do that would specifically eliminate only the 4th gen iPod touch.

You could always require at least iOS 7, which of course would exclude some users of newer devices who haven't upgraded, but it would make the minimum iPhone supported be the iPhone 4, the minimum iPad supported be the iPad 2, and the minimum iPod touch supported be the 5th gen iPod touch. This is the only thing I can see actually working to accomplish what you want here.